# How to fetch values from inventory file in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to fetch the values from the inventory host file but unable to get the values.
Using ansible 2.5.
Thanks in advance.
Please help me with the code in jinja2 template form only.

Host file:

```
[all]
F01 name='["a1","a11"]'  hname='["F01"]'
F02 name='["s01","s11"]' hname='["F02"]'
F03 name='["a02","a12"]' hname='["F03"]'
F04 name='["s02","s12"]' hname='["F04"]'
[nodes]
F01
F02
F03
F04
```

Code, which I used is given below:

dbs is a list

```
dbs = ['a1', 's02', 'a11', 's01', 'a02', 's11', 'a12', 's12']
{% for node, sid in groups['nodes']|zip(dbs) %}
{% for j in hostvars[node]['hname'] if hostvars[node]['name'][0] in dbs %}
< name = "{{ sid }}", hname = "{{ j }}" >
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Required Output:

For every name value it should give the respective hname.

Output should be like below.

```
<name = a1, hname= F01>
<name = s02, hname= F04>
<name = a11, hname= F01>
<name = s01, hname= F02>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the host file the task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "<name = {{ item.0 }}, hname= {{ item.1 }}>"
  loop: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.[name[0], hname[0]]') }}"
```

gives what you want

```
"msg": "<name = s02, hname= F04>"
"msg": "<name = a1, hname= F01>"
"msg": "<name = a02, hname= F03>"
"msg": "<name = s01, hname= F02>"
```

The template is, in fact, the same

```
{% for item in hostvars|json_query('*.[name[0], hname[0]]') %}
<name = {{ item.0 }}, hname= {{ item.1 }}>
{% endfor %}
```

(not tested)

> To take the name value from the dbs list then based on the name value get hname value

The tasks below

```
- set_fact: # get list of names
    names: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.name[0]') }}"
- set_fact: # get list of hashes {name,hname}
    hashes: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.{name: name[0], hname: hname[0]}') }}"
- set_fact: # get list of dict name:hname
    dicts: "{{ dicts|default({})|combine({item: hashes|json_query(query)}) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?name=='{{ item }}'].hname|[0]"
  loop: "{{ names }}"
- debug: # get hname for given name
    msg: "{{ item }}: {{ dicts[item] }}"
  loop: "{{ names }}"
```

give

```
"msg": "s02: F04"
"msg": "a1: F01"
"msg": "a02: F03"
"msg": "s01: F02"
```

The template is, in fact, the same

```
{% for item in names %}
<name = {{ item }}, hname= {{ dicts[item] }}>
{% endfor %}
```

(not tested).

Comment: Hi,
Could you please give me the solution in jinja2 template form by using those kind of for loops which I used in the mentioned code.

Comment: Sure, it's, in fact, the same.

Comment: I have used dbs list in the code so I need the code based on the order of that dbs list. Is it possible in such way?

Comment: We should take the name value from the dbs list then based on the name value we should get hname value.

Comment: Hi Vladmir,
I'm not supposed to use json_query.
I have updated the host and code data.
could you please  suggest me the code in jinja2 form .

Comment: {% for item in names %}
<name = {{ item }}, hname= {{ dicts[item] }}>
{% endfor %}
what comes as names here?
For names value you have used json_query  but  I can't use that one